# QT how to restart a thread?

Tags: qt, qt5

How to properly restart a QThread? I have been googling this four hours and can't find any concrete answer.

What I have is the basic `moveToThread` implementation:

```
VideoHandler::VideoHandler()
{
    VideoBurner *videoBurner = new VideoBurner;
    videoBurner->moveToThread(&videoBurnerThread);

    connect(this, &VideoHandler::signalVideoData, videoBurner, &VideoBurner::setVideoData);
    connect(this, &VideoHandler::signalVideoBurn, videoBurner, &VideoBurner::initVideoBurn);

    // don't really want it since there is only 1 object
    //connect(&videoBurnerThread, &QThread::finished, videoBurner, &QObject::deleteLater);

    connect(videoBurner, &VideoBurner::burnProcess, this, [=](QString step, int percentage){
        emit burningProcess(step, percentage);
    });
}
```

This is the declaration of my Class:

```
class VideoHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread videoBurnerThread;
... 
bunch of defintions
...
}
```

The `VideoBurner` class is also a subclass of `QObject`

```
class VideoBurner : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
bunch of definitions
...
}
```

For the first run this works perfect, signals and slots all work.
The issue happens when I want to "cancel" the thread.
For example it is working on some "heavy" calculation that I want to stop from the main thread so I call: `videoBurnerThread.quit();` with a `cancel` function from `VideoHandler`.

I don't `wait()` on it as it would block the main thread.

`quit()` triggers `&QThread::finished`, but I commented out that connection as it destroys my only object instance.

(also I can't find any example that creates an object and puts it on a thread **outside** a constructor, if that's even possible? when I tried the app would just close without errors)

I found that the `quit()` only stops the event loop, not doing anything besides that, which leads to the issue of `restarting` the tread.

After I want to do the "heavy" stuff again, and I call `videoBurnerThread.start();` to start it again, I get results of last performed function from `VideoBurner` and some `signals` from it, before it actually starts doing what it should.

Can I somehow stop whatever it was working on and just restart it? I tried sending an "abort" signal from `VideoHandler` so it doesn't emit signals, but that didn't work.

Do I absolutely need the `&QObject::deleteLater` so it stops? If so, how to reinitialize `VideoBurner` correctly inside some function and reconnect it's signal/slot?

Also there is no logic in `VideoBurner` destructor just a `public: virtual ~VideoBurner(){};`, could this be an issue?

Comment: To cancel the heavy calculation, you can set a flag and check it periodically during the calculation and quit the calculation gracefully. The thread will be ready to handle the next signal. So you don't need to actually restart the thread, just let its running job finish.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call "this->deleteLater()" at the end of your worker.
2. Connect the worker destroyed signal to the thread quit slot in your Handler function.

Refer to this code snippet.

```
if(!dataThread.isRunning())
{
    worker = new Worker();
    dataThread.setObjectName("dataThread");
    worker->moveToThread(&dataThread);
    QObject::connect(&dataThread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::run);
    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::destroyed, &dataThread, &QThread::quit);
    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::set_counter_label, this, &MainWindow::update_counter);
    dataThread.start();
}
```